Radius of balls in estimates for De Giorgi method
I wanted to ask a question regarding the radius of balls used to get the different estimates to establish both the jump from $L^2$ to $L^{\infty}$ and the Holder continuity later on in the proof of De Giorgi's method. Vasseur and other papers typically use a radius of $1$ and $1/2$ for their estimates, and recently I came across one set of lecture notes that used balls of radius $4$ and $2$ instead.
The method and proofs seem correct there, but I can't really justify to myself the use of larger radii. Is there some covering argument, translation or coordinate change style argument that makes it work, or is there no need for it?

It is possible to move between the two results via rescaling. This is a very important technique in regularity theory. The usual statement of the $L^2$ to $L^\infty$ estimate in De Giorgi-Nash-Moser theory goes something like:

Thm. Let $0<\lambda \leq \Lambda<+\infty$ and $A:B_1\to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix-valued function with measurable coefficients such that $\lambda I_n \leq A(x)\leq \Lambda I_n$ for all $x\in B_1$. If $u \in H^1(B_1)$ is a weak solution of $$\operatorname{div}(A(x)\nabla u) = 0 \qquad \text{in }B_1 $$then $$\| u\|_{L^\infty(B_{1/2})} \leq C \| u \|_{L^2(B_1)}. $$ Here $C>0$ depends only on $n$, $\lambda$, and $\Lambda$.

Now, let $R>0$, $0<\lambda \leq \Lambda<+\infty$ and $A:B_R\to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix-valued function with measurable coefficients such that $\lambda I_n \leq A(x)\leq \Lambda I_n$ for all $x\in B_R$. If $u \in H^1(B_R)$ is a weak solution of $$\operatorname{div}(A(x)\nabla u) = 0 \qquad \text{in }B_R $$then $$\| u\|_{L^\infty(B_{R/2})} \leq C R^{-n/2} \| u \|_{L^2(B_R)}. $$ Here $C>0$ depends only on $n$, $\lambda R^2$, and $\Lambda R^2$.
Indeed, for a function/matrix-valued function $f$, let $f_\rho(x):=f(\rho x)$ for any $\rho>0$. Then, for all $v\in H^1_0(B_1)$, \begin{align*}
\int_{B_1}\nabla v(x) \cdot A_R(x)\nabla u_R(x) \, dx &= R \int_{B_1}\nabla v(x) \cdot A(Rx)\nabla u(Rx) \, dx \\
&=  R^{1-n} \int_{B_R}\nabla v(x/R) \cdot A(x)\nabla u(x) \, dx\\
&= R^{2-n} \int_{B_R}\nabla v_{R^{-1}}(x) \cdot A(x)\nabla u(x) \, dx\\
&=0
\end{align*} since $v_{R^{-1}} \in H^1_0(B_R)$. Hence, $u_R$ satisfies $$\operatorname {div} (A_{R}(x) \nabla u_R ) \qquad \text{in } B_1 $$ in the weak sense. Since $0<\lambda R^2 I_n \leq A_R \leq \Lambda R^2 I_n$ in $B_1$, it follows that $$\| u_R\|_{L^\infty(B_{1/2})} \leq C \| u_R\|_{L^2(B_1)} $$ with $C$ depending only on $n$, $\lambda R^2$, and $\Lambda R^2$. Then $\| u_R\|_{L^\infty(B_{1/2})} = \| u\|_{L^\infty(B_{R/2})}$ and $\| u_R\|_{L^2(B_1)} = R^{-n/2}\| u\|_{L^2(B_R)}$
In particular, choosing $R=4$ you get the result in the lecture notes you found. It’s also not hard to see that if you know the result holds in balls of radius of 4 and 2, you can do the same thing to obtain the result in balls of radius 1 and 1/2.
By a more sophisticated argument you can actually prove the result in $\Omega$ and $\Omega’$ with $\Omega’\subset \subset \Omega$, see Remark 2.15 in Regularity theory for elliptic PDE by Fernadez-Real and Ros-Oton.

Thank you lots for this. I sort of figured out that if we prove this for a larger radius, it should hold for smaller balls naturally but the other way around was a little problematic. Just to be sure, the result is local in nature, i.e., we prove that the minimizers are smooth for each compact subset, thanks to those estimates on the balls, of some bounded and open domain, right?

Also, they don't impose the constraint of the $L^{2}$ norm of the solution being less than some $\delta$ when they first prove the jump from $L^{2}$ to $L^{\infty}$. Instead, they construct an inequality where a smaller $L^p$ norm bounds a larger $L^q$ norm on a ball of a smaller radius, which then they send to their limit cases of $L^2$ on a ball of radius $4$ and $L^{\infty}$ on the ball of radius 2. Is the norm constraint there only because Vasseur and other authors typically construct the non-linear estimate for which it is needed?

For your first comment, I assume now that you’re referring to the solution to Hilbert’s XIX-th problem because, if you only have $A$ as above, this is the best you can do (for higher regularity of $u$ you need higher regularity of $A$)

But yes, if you have a minimiser in $B_1$ then the above estimates (+ bootstrapping, etc.) on balls imply that $u$ is smooth on $\Omega’\subset \subset B_1$ with uniform estimates. In particular, this implies $u$ is smooth on $B_1$, but you don’t get the inequality on all of $B_1$ (so $u$ is not smooth in $\overline{B_1}$)

I don’t understand your second question, sorry. What do you mean by the non-linear estimate? Taking the $L^2$ norm smaller than $\delta>0$ with $\delta$ small can be assumed without loss of generality and it makes the proof simpler which is why most proofs do this

Apologies for a poorly asked question. It took me a while to find the lectures notes online to provide you with a link -
https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/nashmoser.pdf
The question I meant was more in the lines of - Is the requirement for the $L^{2}$ norm to be smaller than some $\delta$ necessary? As you can see, in their theorem 1, they don't really make that assumption, which made me wonder as to how I can make both approaches equivalent.
